# Add a calculated HH:MM:SS to the Current time in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time, date, rendering

I've made a spreadsheet to quickly calculate how long a 3D render will take based on number of frames & minutes per frame.

However I'm also wanting to add a calculation that shows the time and date the render would finish, if the render was to start at the current time.

Similar to how this website works: http://www.simonreeves.com/rendertimecalc/

Currently I have the render time formula working, which gives me a HH:MM:SS result, and I also have the current time in a cell as `=NOW()`, but I'd like a formula that adds together the HH:MM:SS result to the current time, in order to give me a real world 'finish time'.

Is this possible at all?

I tried `=NOW()+E20` (E20 being my render time result cell), but that just gives me a long number such as `1026978:02:54`...

Comment: sounds like a cell formatting issue. Are both cells actual time values or did you construct your rendertime as a combination of numbers and colons manually? Also there are two types of time formattings in excel, basically a date and a timespan. you want to add a timespan to a date and format the result as a date. maybe you simply formatted your result as a timespan, that might explain the large amount of hours.

Comment: I just tried `=NOW()+H4` (H4 containing a time in HH:MM:SS format) And it calculated without a problem. So your function should be valid. Maybe check the cell formatting?

Comment: Format the cell as Custom and select `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` in Number Group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the cell as Custom and select dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss in Number Group

[image]